# How do I force the player in a text-based game to use an alphabet-only name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character, naming, alphabet

So this is my code:

```
name = input("So, what is your name? ")
    if name.isalpha():
    print ("So your name is " +(name) + "? Awesome.")
    else:
    print ("That's not a real name! Try again...")
```

I want to figure out how to return to the original question after the player doesn't type in a real name. This is my first day of using Python (and any language, really) so don't use anything too advanced for me :)

Also, how can I make the first letter of the players name automatically capitalize if it isn't already?

Comment: PLEASE read this post: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [while](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) loop like this

```
name = input("So, what is your name? ")
while not name.isalpha():
    print ("That's not a real name! Try again...")
    name = input("So, what is your name? ")
print ("So your name is " +(name) + "? Awesome.")
```

First, it gets the name, and the `while` loop makes sure that as long as the `name` not only has alphabets, it will print `That's not a real name! Try again...` and take input for `name`. If the `name` has only alphabets it automatically breaks out of the loop and prints `"So your name is <name entered>? Awesome."`

**Edit:** To make the first character an uppercase letter, you can use [title](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) function and instead of concatenating strings, you can [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) them like this.

```
print ("So your name is {}? Awesome.".format(name.title()))
```

Comment: Ok. Wait. This comment section is annoying :| Thanks @thefourtheye! I didn't know I could do that. I was doing something similar, but instead I would set a new variable equal to the old variable, but capitalized and that didn't work, but what you said did work!

Comment: Then just do `name = name.title()`